# Meaning of Network Manager Dbus codes 'aa{ss}'

Tags: dbus, gdbus, networkmanager

I am making a script to do IO to the NetworkManager over dbus. In the [gnome developer docs](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager) function arguments are represented as things like `'aa{ss}'` but i cannot find a description of there meaning.

[Example](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.IP4Config.html#gdbus-property-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager-IP4Config.Routes)

```
RouteData  readable   aa{sv} """<-this guy"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone from the Gnome IRC was able to help me posting here in case somone else gets stuck.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-format-strings.html

so aa{sv} means

```
array array dict(string,variant)
```